# how to add next and previous button on my lightbox div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please help me to add next and Previous Buttons in this light box i want to add

```
<div id="next">Next</div>
<div id="pre">Prev</div>
```

in my lightbox. is there a simple way to add Next and Previous buttons inside the light box.when i click on next button it open next cont-href box with next and previous button and same as previous Button .

```js
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $('.cont-wrap > .cont-lnk').click( function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.active > .cont-href, .overlay').show();
    });
    function dDb() {
    $('.active > .cont-href, .overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.cont-lnk').removeClass('active'); 
    };
    
    $('.overlay, .close').click( function () {
     dDb();
     });
    $('.cont-href').click( function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
    
    });
```

```css
body {
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
    }
    .cont-lnk {
     display:block;
     width:100px;
     background:#999;
     height:20px;
    }
    .cont-href {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 35%;
    height: 200px;
    }
    .overlay {
     background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     z-index:999;
     display:none;
    }
    .close {
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     right:10px;
     top:10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="mwrap">
    <div class="cont-wrap">
    <div class="cont-lnk">
    Click here
    <div class="cont-href">
    <div class="close"><a href="#">X</a></div>
    box content comes here.....
    <div id="next">next</div>
    <div id="prev">pre</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-wrap">
    <div class="cont-lnk">
    Click here 2
    <div class="cont-href">
    <div class="close"><a href="#">X</a></div>
    box content comes here 2 bla bla.....
    <div id="next">next</div>
    <div id="prev">pre</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't lightbox set this up for you? All you need to do is copy and paste. At least that's how I remember it being. Also you should try formatting your code.

Comment: how to set formatting can u guide me i am new here.... :/

Comment: @Ruddy I don't think the OP is using a library, but yeah: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2 does/can

Comment: this is my light box [link](http://jsfiddle.net/najamali/FLmrq/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your fiddle change the next and prev id into classes (not a good practice to have identical ids for multiple elements), then add this code:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
        $('.active > .cont-href, .overlay').hide();
        $(this).closest(".cont-lnk").removeClass('active');
        var currentContWrap = $(this).closest(".cont-wrap");
        var nextContWrap = currentContWrap.next(".cont-wrap");
        nextContWrap.children(".cont-lnk").addClass('active');
        $('.active > .cont-href, .overlay').show();
    });
    $(".prev").click(function() {
        $('.active > .cont-href, .overlay').hide();
        $(this).closest(".cont-lnk").removeClass('active');
        var currentContWrap = $(this).closest(".cont-wrap");
        var prevContWrap = currentContWrap.prev(".cont-wrap");
        prevContWrap.children(".cont-lnk").addClass('active');
        $('.active > .cont-href, .overlay').show();
    });
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hEEFq/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an id in the one document page more then once.